# Retanguloids and volumes

Tags: analysis, geometry

I am currently going back through all the "Challenge" questions in preparation for exams, and have come across this, any hints on how to approach?

[image]

Comment: A rectanguloid of side lengths $x,y,z$, has surface area $2(xy+yz+zx)$, and we know $xy+yz+zx \geq 3(xyz)^{\frac23}$, by AM-GM, and equality holds iff $x=y=z$

Comment: sorry, what is AM-GM? and by equality ,what are we equating?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means , with 3 terms it yields $\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{xy.yz.zx}]$. The surface area $S=2(xy+yz+zx)$ and volume is $V=xyz$, thus we get $S \ge 6V^{\frac23}$, the maximum $V$ occurs when $V=(S/6)^{\frac32}$ .. that is the equality condition for the AM-GM Inequality, which is $xy=yz=zx$, which means $x=y=z$, that is a cube.

Comment: Yep got it, Thank you!